# What kind of molex(?) connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

Trying to repair an electric mattress pad and need to ID this connector [image: connector]

Comment: A blurry white one? :) Might be an MLX power type with 3 wires, though.

Comment: Thanks, sounds about right. Sorry for the blurry pic, cropped from a larger photo.

Comment: What's the pin pitch? It might be Molex, might be TE/Amp.

Comment: Actually what I really need to know is the kind of pin used inside (so I can replace it), I figure there must be a lot fewer varieties of pins than connectors

Answer (score 4):

TE, Universal MATE-N-LOK II

Found using my [connector identification utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=rectangular_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=partitioned_shroud_conn&f=partitioned_shroud_latch_conn_6&s=Universal%20MATE-N-LOK%20II%20(3r))

[TE 350767-1](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-350767-1.html)

[image: TE 350767-1]

{Picture from Digikey's website}

You can buy it from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/350767-1/213747?s=N4IgTCBcDaIMwFYAMB2AbCgtARhAXQF8g). The contacts are listed at the bottom of that page.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you!

Comment: Are all Mate-N-Lok connector pins interchangeable (same pin length and diameter, different only in wire gauge/material/finish/packaging)? The fools used 28AWG wire in a 14-20AWG pin, so I thought I'd get the right gauge pin.

Comment: No, They are not. Pins come in 3 mating diameters, and pitches vary allover the place.

Comment: I thought pitch was the center-to-center distance between pins, so that would be a spec of the connector housing, not the pin, no? Or is this a different pitch? Is there an easy overview guide for the world of connectors?

Comment: "I thought pitch was the center-to-center distance between pin". Yes, it is.  "so that would be a spec of the connector housing, not the pin, no". Correct. "Or is this a different pitch?" In this family you can have different pitches for different number of contacts, even if they all use the same pin size. That's uncommon. Normally, a family of connectors all have the same pitch.

Comment: " Is there an easy overview guide for the world of connectors?" I am writing it now: https://connectorbook.com/

Comment: Book looks great, will make a great resource! I just went with the pins shown at the bottom of the Digi-key page and fixed my device...luckily even had the right crimp tool die for them!